# angularjs compare row values

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angularjs and don't know where to start to accomplish the below task. Any help is greatly appreciated.

In the attached image , how can I make

1. validate the value entered in column Actual Value is b/w Lower spec and Upper spec ?.
2. If user enters value outside the range , then I need to force the user add Notes for that row.
3. Submit button needs to be disabled until valid values and notes are added.
   [image]

here is the html code
  {{group.LowerSpecLimit | number:4 }}
                                              {{group.UpperSpecLimit | number:4 }}

```
                                        <td class="col-md-3">

                                            <input ng-show="group.ValueEntered < 12 "
                                                   style="border-left: solid red"
                                                   ng-required="group.ValueEntered < 12"
                                                   class="form-control"
                                                   id="notes"
                                                   name="notes"
                                                   type="text"
                                                   placeholder="Notes"
                                                   ng-model="group.Notes">

                                            <input ng-show="group.ValueEntered > 12 "
                                                   style="border-left: solid green"
                                                   class="form-control"
                                                   id="notes"
                                                   name="notes"
                                                   type="text"
                                                   placeholder="Notes"
                                                   ng-model="group.Notes">

                                        </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

This fiddle is what you are aiming for:
http://jsfiddle.net/ernestsoo22/uptnx/804/

To check whether or not the actual value is within range. `ng-model` is used to bind the user's input with a application data named `actualvalue` (see fiddle). 
**Note:** Initialise with `ng-init`.

`ng-show` is used to display different input fields **required notes** and **notes**.

`ng-required` is used to conditionally check whether or not the **required notes** field is filled based on an expression.

To disable the submit button, use `ng-disabled`.

You should be able to tweak the fiddle presented to suit your needs.

Comment: I was able to add your code . But the area with input boxes kind of flashes while hiding and showing the other input box. I have updated my code with html code. Any idea whats happening ?

Comment: @bp581 There is a minor error for your conditions in ng-show. If one of them is group.ValueEntered > 12, The other should be group.ValueEntered <= 12 (purely based on what you need). I am suspecting that your input box hides when the input box has the number 12 for a brief moment because both ng-show expressions evaluates to false.

Comment: I made the change..no luck yet.

Comment: Try using `ng-hide` with reverse conditions. Eg. `ng-show="variable > 12"` would be `ng-hide="variable <= 12` . This way, the input box will not be hidden unless the expressions evaluates to true. I notice that on the fiddle, input box would be hidden if an alphabet is keyed as an input instead of an integer. @bp581

Comment: sorry not working with ng-hide . The screen still flashes just like ng-show